# Having trouble using iterators erase a vector item every M number of passes

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, stdvector

I have been having some issues with implementing a vector. The program that I'm attempting to make does as follows: takes a user defined "size" value and creates a "circular" vector of that size. Then it takes in another integer variable that represents how many iterations of the loop must happen before an item gets deleted from the vector. In my code, I am attempting to iterate through this vector of "Person" objects (a basic class whose only private data member is an integer representing a position). The class that this "runProgram" function is declared in has a private data member of a vector of person objects, then three integers representing the circle size, the number of passes before elimination, and the amount of items in the vector.  I have made a while loop to carry-out this procedure. However, every time I run this program, the program seems to make only one pass through the loop, and then delete everything... or just not continue. Here is some of my code:

The main loop:

```
enter cod int VectorMyJosephus::runProgram(){
int n = 0;
int m = 0;

cout << "How many people would you like in the circle?" << endl;
cin >> n;
cout << "How many passes would you like ther to be before someone is eliminated?" << endl;
cin >> m;

init(n, m);

vector<Person>::iterator iter;
iter = circ.begin();
int count = 0;

while (circ.size() > 1)
{
    //count the current person
    count += 1;
    iter->print();

    //remove every "M" person
    if (count == M)
    {
        iter = circ.erase(iter);
        count = 0;
        size -= 1;
        /*printAll();
        system("PAUSE");*/
    }
    else
    {
        //contine through the list once someone was removed
        ++iter;
    }

    if (iter == circ.end())
    {
        iter = circ.begin();
    }


    cout << "The position of the only remaining person is: " << iter->getPosition() << "\n" << endl;
    cout << circ.size() << endl;


    return 0;

}
```

}e here

Here is my initialization function that is supposed to populate the vector with person objects:

```
   void VectorMyJosephus::init(int N, int M)
{
    this->setN(N);
    this->setM(M);
    this->setSize(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        Person pers;
        pers.setPosition(i);
        circ.push_back(pers);
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner, so any help whatsoever is greatly appreciated

Comment: You have a `return 0;` statement inside the `while` loop scope, that's why you have only one iteration.

Comment: Thank you Sergey Shevchenko. That is such a silly mistake by me. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You have `return 0` inside your while loop, which breaks loop execution immediately.

Comment: Hey thanks Gover Nator. That was a dumb mistake from me